# Go runtime error: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, goroutine

My code run normaly in a few second but after that, it throws an error:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer
> dereference
>
> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer
> dereference [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1
> addr=0x328 pc=0x58d086]
>
> goroutine 1884 [running]: crypto/tls.(*Conn).Close(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
> /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:1310 +0x26 panic(0x5dcc60, 0x73dc30)
> /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:965 +0x1b9 crypto/tls.(*Conn).Write(0x0, 0xc000701fb0, 0x23, 0x30, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
> /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:1101 +0x66 main.main.func1(0xc0000aa270, 0xd, 0x60d313, 0x9)
> /home/nt-user/workspace/Main.go:28 +0x19b created by main.main
> /home/nt-user/workspace/Main.go:18 +0xbf exit status 2

```
package main

import (
    //"net"
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "crypto/tls"
)

func main() {
    var (
        targetHost = "Website URL"
        targetPort = "443"
        targetURL = targetHost + ":" + targetPort
    )
    for true {
        for i := 0; i < 500; i++ {
            go func() {
               var s, err = tls.Dial("tcp", targetURL, &tls.Config {
                   ServerName: targetHost,
                   InsecureSkipVerify: true,
               })
               if err != nil {
                   fmt.Println("Error when connect to " + targetHost)
               }
               defer s.Close()
               for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
                   s.Write([]byte("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + targetHost + "\r\n\r\n"))
               }
            }()
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your program continues running even if there is a connection error.

Comment: It exits after throws that error

Comment: It continues runing if  `tls.Dial` fails with `s` being nil, and when you call `s.Write` you get a nil pointer dereference, because `Dial` failed. Then it exits.

Comment: So can you guide me how to fix it, I am new with Go

Comment: If err is not nil, you should return from the goroutine after you print the error

Comment: @StupidCheems in Go, if you have a function that has multiple return values and one of them is of the `error` type, and a call to such a function results in a non-nil error, then the other values are, generally, *unusable*. And if you try to use those other values anyway the program will either panic or produce bad results. So, generally, you handle errors the following way: `if err != nil { return }` and NOT `if err != nil { print }`.

Answer (score 1):

In your go func, after `tls.Dial`, if it is getting error, it will continue and use `nil s` in `s.Write`. That's why panic happens. So return if there is an error.

```
               var s, err = tls.Dial("tcp", targetURL, &tls.Config {
                   ServerName: targetHost,
                   InsecureSkipVerify: true,
               })
               if err != nil {
                   fmt.Println("Error when connect to " + targetHost)
                   return //return here, otherwise it continues to use nil "s"
               }
```

I prefer not to print error. Log it in your preferred logger or send it to an error channel and handle errors separately.

Answer (score -1):

Let me know if this helps you

```
for i := 0; i < 500; i++ {
 go func() {
          var s, err = tls.Dial("tcp", targetURL, &tls.Config {
                   ServerName: targetHost,
                   InsecureSkipVerify: true,
          })
          defer s.Close() // moved to here
          if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error when connect to " + targetHost)
            return
          }
         
          for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
             s.Write([]byte("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + targetHost + "\r\n\r\n"))
          }
       }()
  time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // give some delay
}
```

Comment: @mkopriva Oops sorry for that...it should be "return"- updated the answer